# JavaScript instanceof

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Can you please tell my why in the example below `sub instanceof Super` is `false`?

```
function Super(){
    var obj = {
        prop1: "value1"
    };
    return obj;
}

var sub = new Super();
sub instanceof Super // false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because its not an instance of that type - you've returned an anonymous object. If you would have written it like this:

```
function Super(){
 this.prop1 = 'value1';   
}

var sub = new Super();
console.log(sub instanceof Super) // true
```

It would work as intended

Comment: Please be so kind and go into more details with `Because its not an instance of that type`

Comment: @User789 - I did, it's right after the hyphen in that sentence.